# Is it possible to use Ip address instead of localhost in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I used to deploy my laravel application into server. Is there any way to change the localhost:8000 into ip of remote machine or is it possible to change port number 8000 into 80?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get it to work outside of localhost, do php artisan serve --host x.x.x.x

If you want it to work without specifying the port in the browser, php artisan serve --host x.x.x.x --port 80. sudo will likely be required on mac.

Note: php artisan serve should never be used for production. It's for dev and demonstration only and won't be able to handle more than a person or two's worth of traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you mean, but you can't point localhost to a remote ip.